# MongoDB: Get _id of last insert

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm interested in how to do this through the wire protocol, as I'm writing my own driver. It seems that PHP automatically modifies the array to contain _id field. How specifically does it do that? What command/query is sent to the mongod server?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Many of the drivers from 10Gen generate it on the client (as you could see by looking at the open source implementations of the drivers). What's the issue? What have you tried? What language are you writing a driver for?

Comment: It's worth noting that BSON IDs are almost always client-generated; their spec is specifically designed to allow them to be generated by distributed clients without collision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your driver needs to provide the _id of the last insert, the easiest way is to generate the _id on the client if it's not already part of the document you get from the programmer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the php driver, but going through the code of the Java driver, if an id is not provided, [this code is executed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/src/main/org/bson/types/ObjectId.java) (at line 169):

```
public ObjectId() {
    _time = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
    _machine = _genmachine;
    _inc = _nextInc.getAndIncrement();
    _new = true;
}
```

to return a new default `ObjectId`.